# SQLalchemy, how to replace the foreign-key ids with the foreign-key attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, foreign-keys

I have a data-model built by SQLalchemy ORM, following shows an entry in scenario table:

```
>>>dbsce
DBScenario(id=1, status=RUNOK, description=None, network_id=1, name=TBD, configuration=None)
```

which also have parameters as list:

```
>>>dbsce.parameters
[DBScePar(scenario_id=1, node_id=1, value=3.4, id=1, element_id=None, parameter=Q, unit=MW),
 DBScePar(scenario_id=1, node_id=None, value=2, id=10151, element_id=2, parameter=V, unit=m/s),
 ...]
```

As you can see sometimes `dbsce.parameters`, has `node_id` and sometimes they have `element_id` (they are foreignkeys). I can reach the specific node or element via:

```
>>>dbsce.parameters[0].node
DBNode(network_id=1, name=Node1, type=256, y=52.0, id=1, alias=TBD, subsys=DEFAULT, x=6.0, height=0.0)
>>>dbsce.parameters[1].element
DBElement(..., name=Element1, ...)
```

**I would like to update or get the `dbsce.parameter` list with the names of the nodes and elements instead of `node_id/element_id`. Is there a unique sqlalchemy-way to do that?**

At the moment, I am doing over the sql-syntax (see below) via joining these tables in the query. However, I would prefer doing that in python via sqlalchemy.

Expected outcome is something like this:

```
>>>parameters
[DBScePar(scenario_id=1, node_name=Node1, value=3.4, id=1, element_name=None, parameter=Q, unit=MW),
 DBScePar(scenario_id=1, node_name=None, value=2, id=10151, element_name=Element1, parameter=V, unit=m/s),
 ...]
```

Current status:

```
with Session(db.engine) as session:
    query = (session.query(DBNode.name,
                           DBElement.name,
                           DBScePar.parameter,
                           DBScePar.value,
                           DBScePar.unit)
             .join(DBNode, DBScePar.node_id == DBNode.id,
                   isouter=True)
             .join(DBElement, DBScePar.element_id == DBElement.id,
                   isouter=True)
             .join(DBScenario, DBScePar.scenario_id == DBScenario.id)
             .join(DBNetwork, DBScenario.network_id == DBNetwork.id)
             .filter(DBNetwork.name == net, DBScenario.name == sce))
    dbpar = query.all()
```